Avatar doesn't fetch from firebase
I create for my flutter app the page where it displays other users profile but their profile picture doesn't fetch from firebase. What I should add to the code? or should I change the way it's fetching in MyProfileScreen.dart to somehow recognise the user that is adding this information . This is the issue https://imgur.com/a/De2HHBa
       class ViewUserProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userId;

  ViewUserProfile({required this.userId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print('Error fetching user data: ${snapshot.error}');
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          }

          if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data!.exists) {
            print('User data not found for userId: $userId');
            return Center(child: Text('User not found'));
          }

          var userData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>? ?? {};
          var avatarUrl = userData['profilePicture'] as String?;
          var name = userData['name'] as String? ?? 'Unknown';
          var instagramHandle = userData['instagramName'] as String? ?? '';

          final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
          final coverHeight = screenWidth * 0.9;

          return DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // Spacing at the top
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                // White widget with rounded corners
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        // Blurred background
                        BlurredBackground(imageUrl: avatarUrl, height: coverHeight),
                        BackdropFilter(
                          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
                          child: Container(
                            height: coverHeight,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            child: Stack(
                              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              children: [
                                // Workout Programs
                                Positioned(
                                  left: 20,
                                  top: 20,
                                  child: _buildProgramInfo(
                                    'Workout Programs',
                                    'Workout',
                                    Color(0xFF00FF00), // Neon green
                                    FontAwesomeIcons.dumbbell,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // Diet Programs (now under Workout Programs)
                                Positioned(
                                  left: 20,
                                  top: 80, // Adjusted to be below Workout Programs
                                  child: _buildProgramInfo(
                                    'Diet Programs',
                                    'Diet',
                                    Color(0xFFFF8C00), // Dark orange
                                    FontAwesomeIcons.utensils,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // Avatar
                                Positioned(
                                  top: coverHeight * 0.3,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          boxShadow: [
                                            BoxShadow(
                                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                                              spreadRadius: 2,
                                              blurRadius: 10,
                                              offset: Offset(0, 3),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                          child: CircleAvatar(
                                            radius: 50,
                                            backgroundImage: avatarUrl != null
                                              ? CachedNetworkImageProvider(avatarUrl) as ImageProvider
                                              : AssetImage('assets/default_avatar.png'),
                                            onBackgroundImageError: (exception, stackTrace) {
                                              print('Error loading avatar: $exception');
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // Name and Instagram Handle
                                Positioned(
                                  top: coverHeight * 0.7,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        name,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20, 
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                                      Text(
                                        '@$instagramHandle',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14, 
                                          color: Colors.black54,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // Add Subscribers info
                                Positioned(
                                  right: 20,
                                  top: 20,
                                  child: _buildSubscribersInfo(),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                // Additional spacing between white widget and TabBar
                SizedBox(height: 24),
                // TabBar
                TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'Workout'),
                    Tab(text: 'Diet'),
                  ],
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                ),
                // TabBarView
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      WorkoutTab(userId: userId),
                      DietTab(userId: userId),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildProgramInfo(String title, String category, Color color, IconData icon) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Icon(icon, color: color, size: 20),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 4),
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('programs')
              .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
              .where('category', isEqualTo: category)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            int count = snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data!.docs.length : 0;
            return Text(
              '$count ${category.toLowerCase()} programs',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 14),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSubscribersInfo() {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
        var userData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        int subscribersCount = userData['subscribersCount'] ?? 0;
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Text(
              '$subscribersCount',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Subscribers',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 14),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class WorkoutTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userId;

  WorkoutTab({required this.userId});

  Future<String?> _getImageUrl(String? imageName) async {
    if (imageName == null) {
      print('Image name is null');
      return null;
    }
    try {
      print('Fetching image URL for: program_covers/$imageName');
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('program_covers/$imageName');
      // Check if the file exists
      try {
        await ref.getMetadata();
      } catch (e) {
        print('File does not exist in Storage: program_covers/$imageName');
        return null;
      }
      final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      print('Successfully fetched URL: $url');
      return url;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching image URL for $imageName: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building WorkoutTab for user: $userId');
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('programs')
          .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
          .where('category', isEqualTo: 'Workout')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          print('Waiting for data...');
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print('Error fetching workout programs: ${snapshot.error}');
          return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
        }

        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
          print('No workout programs found for user: $userId');
          return Center(child: Text('No workout programs found'));
        }

        print('Found ${snapshot.data!.docs.length} workout programs');

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var programData = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            print('Program data: $programData'); // Add this line
            
            String title = programData['title'] as String? ?? 'Untitled Program';
            String? imageName = programData['image'] as String?;
            int subscribersCount = programData['subscribersCount'] as int? ?? 0;
            double rating = (programData['rating'] as num?)?.toDouble() ?? 0.0;

            print('Program $index: $title, Image: $imageName');

            return FutureBuilder<String?>(
              future: _getImageUrl(imageName),
              builder: (context, imageSnapshot) {
                if (imageSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  print('Waiting for image URL...');
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }

                if (imageSnapshot.hasError) {
                  print('Error loading image: ${imageSnapshot.error}');
                  return Text('Error loading image');
                }

                String? imageUrl = imageSnapshot.data;
                print('Image URL: $imageUrl');

                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: 2,
                          blurRadius: 5,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(15)),
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                            child: imageUrl != null
                                ? CachedNetworkImage(
                                    imageUrl: imageUrl,
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    placeholder: (context, url) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) {
                                      print('Error displaying image: $error');
                                      return Icon(Icons.error);
                                    },
                                  )
                                : Container(
                                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                                    child: Icon(Icons.image, size: 50, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                                  ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                title,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 16),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(Icons.person, size: 16, color: Colors.grey),
                                      SizedBox(width: 4),
                                      Text('$subscribersCount subscribers'),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(Icons.star, size: 16, color: Colors.amber),
                                      SizedBox(width: 4),
                                      Text(rating.toStringAsFixed(1)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class DietTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userId;

  DietTab({required this.userId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Fetching diet programs for user: $userId'); // Debug log
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('programs')
          .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
          .where('category', isEqualTo: 'Diet')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print('Error fetching diet programs: ${snapshot.error}');
          return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
        }

        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          print('No data received from Firestore'); // Debug log
          return Center(child: Text('No data available'));
        }

        if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
          print('Query returned empty result'); // Debug log
          return Center(child: Text('No diet programs found'));
        }

        print('Found ${snapshot.data!.docs.length} diet programs'); // Debug log

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var programData = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            
            String title = programData['title'] as String? ?? 'Untitled Diet Program';
            String description = programData['description'] as String? ?? 'No description available';
            String? imageUrl = programData['image'] as String?;

            print('Program $index: $title'); // Debug log

            return Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  if (imageUrl != null)
                    CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: imageUrl,
                      height: 200,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      placeholder: (context, url) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                    ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          title,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8),
                        Text(description),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class BlurredBackground extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? imageUrl;
  final double height;

  BlurredBackground({required this.imageUrl, required this.height});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return imageUrl != null
        ? CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: imageUrl!,
            height: height,
            width: double.infinity,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            placeholder: (context, url) => Container(color: Colors.grey[200]),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(color: Colors.grey[200]),
            imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: imageProvider,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            height: height,
            color: Colors.grey[200],
          );
  }
}


There is not enough debugging information and too much code here for us to efficiently help. While it's always possible that somebody spots the problem and answers, chances of that drastically go up if you isolate the problem and provide more easy to digest debugging information than a video. I recommend reading How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and update your question to match that.

E.g. if you remove everything that is not related to the problem from the app, and just load the profilePicture and print that, does the URL look like what you'd expect? If you open the URL in just a browser window/tab, does it show what you expect? If you show the avatarUrl in a Image.network rather than a BlurredBackground, does it show what you expect?
